# How to get just two items of a json like file

Tags: awk, command-line, json, sublime-text

I'm trying to parse the `Sublime Text 3` session file: **Session.sublime_session**. It consist of what look like JSON formatted stuff.

Using:

```bsh
cat Session.sublime_session | grep -A13 "\"file\":"
```

I can get easily get a list (repeated for each file) like this:

```
    "file": "/F/myHW/check_usb_switch.sh",
    "semi_transient": false,
    "settings":
    {
            "buffer_size": 873,
            "regions":
            {
            },
            "selection":
            [
                    [
                            872,
                            872
                    ]
--
```

How can I get a list like this:

```
/F/myHW/check_usb_switch.sh:872
...
```

(Are there other or more suitable tools for this? (E.g. **`jq`** etc?)

---

Requested info:

```
# Start of file:
{
        "folder_history":
        [
        ],
        "last_version": 3176,
        "last_window_id": 9,
        "log_indexing": false,
        "settings":
        {
                "new_window_height": 912.0,
                "new_window_settings":
                {
                        "auto_complete":
                        {
                                "selected_items":
                                [
                                        [
                                                "input",
                                                "input_stream"
                                        ],
...
        },
        "windows":
        [
                {
                        "auto_complete":
                        {
                                "selected_items":
                                [
                                        [
                                                "file",
                                                "fileName"
...
                                        [
                                                "json",
                                                "json_response"
                                        ]
                                ]
                        },
                        "buffers":
                        [
                                {
                                        "file": "/F/xxxx.sh",
                                        "settings":
                                        {
                                                "buffer_size": 7040,
                                                "encoding": "UTF-8",
                                                "line_ending": "Unix"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "file": "/C/xxxx.txt",
```

---

Request-2:

```
                                                {
                                                        "buffer": 1,
                                                        "file": "/C/Users/xxxx/Desktop/tmp/xxxx.txt",
                                                        "semi_transient": false,
                                                        "settings":
                                                        {
                                                                "buffer_size": 6529,
                                                                "regions":
                                                                {
                                                                },
                                                                "selection":
                                                                [
                                                                        [
                                                                                3569,
                                                                                3569
                                                                        ]
                                                                ],
                                                                "settings":
                                                                {
                                                                        "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage",
                                                                        "word_wrap": false
                                                                },
                                                                "translation.x": 0.0,
                                                                "translation.y": 0.0,
                                                                "zoom_level": 1.0
                                                        },
                                                        "stack_index": 46,
                                                        "type": "text"
                                                },
```

Comment: How do you define bash tools?  `grep` isn't one of them.

Comment: Ah, well standard linux tools. whatever that come with the OS really.

Comment: Can you make your input valid JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure that the Sublime is valid JSON or not. I can only guess that it is...

Comment: Showing the structure of the JSON document would be vital for us to be able to show you the correct parsing of the data using a readily available JSON parser.  `grep` is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: It looks like it could be valid if you include more of it, we would need at least the entire **object** that contains the `file` key, you can test if it's valid json using https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: It is valid. But my file is 177 kB... What exactly do you need. (There's too much personal info to post it all here.)

Comment: a json object should be surrounded in `{ }` brackets.  Can you extract at least one complete object that contains the `file` key?

Comment: Also how do you determine which of the values in the "selection" array will be used?  Or will they always be identical?

Comment: You have posted more invalid JSON, every opening bracket must have a closing bracket.

Comment: Just the first one will suffice. The second one is only different if a code snippet was selected.

Comment: Your second sample input also does not contain any `selection` array

Comment: It would be much better if you removed all your input and compiled a **single and complete** sample input rather than _three separate and equally incomplete_ ones.

Comment: I know! This is a catch-22. I need the list to close down all the other files before I can provide something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jq -r '.windows[]|.buffers[]|.file' Session.sublime_session
```

This would use the JSON parser `jq` to parse out all the `file` nodes from each buffer of each window recorded in the Sublime Text 3 sessions file.

To get the `file` info together with the first integer of the `selection` bit, you will have to look elsewhere in the data:

```
jq -r '.windows[]|.groups[].sheets[]| "\(.file):\(.settings.selection[0][0])"' Session.sublime_session
```

Note that the `file` field is taken from a totally different place in the document compared to the first command.

On a small example file I played around with, this may generate

```
/Users/kk/hello:18
```

as output.

(tested on a session file on macOS where I worked on a file called `hello` in my home directory)

Unfortunately, I have not found any documentation on the schema used for these JSON files, so the parsing here is totally ad-hoc.

Comment: OP also wants the first value from the unnamed array inside the selection array.

Comment: Yeah, that gives the file list, but I want the *`selection`* number as well. The *selection* is the current cursor byte location.

Comment: @not2qubit: From your input it looks like not every `file` has an associated `selection` array, but I can't tell because your input is atrocious

Comment: @not2qubit I'm working on it. I just managed to recreate such a selection, it's not in `.buffers` at all... Hold on.

Comment: @Jesse_b Every file has this field, but it can be zero: `[[0,0]]`.

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the super quick fix effort. I was looking at `jq` but found it a bit daunting in the formatting. But it seem very effective once you know it.

Comment: Now the only thing left for me to do to make my day perfect, is to use that number (byte offset) to get the line number by reading that many bytes, then count EOL's in that blob.

Comment: @not2qubit That sounds like a new question, but `head -c number file | wc -l` might get you started (where `number` is the number, and `file` is the filename).